# Static cell has background color on iPhone, but not on iPad - can not find the reason

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, adaptive-layout

In an iOS 8 project with storyboard and adaptive layout (aka size classes) I use static cells in 2 scenes -

And for some reason the blueish background color of the top cell is not shown on iPad:

[image: screenshots]

Please, what could be the reason for that?

I've even searched with debugger (stepped through viewDidLoad) and in XML-code of Main.storyboard - and can not find the cause.

I have reset the simulator settings too and have tried on Yosemite and Mavericks macs that I have.

Here is my storyboard (please [click for fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8InI.png)) where I set the background color (for **wAny** and **hAny**):

[image: Xcode]

In the preview (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsKX7.png)) the background color is present in both iPad and iPhone:

[image: Preview]

If I have done anything wrong here, how to find and reset this?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried DCGoD's suggestion (thanks) - and it works. When I try setting the cells background color with the following code it works (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6UO.png)):

[image: screenshots]

```
#define THEME_COLOR_BLUE [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255 green:175.0/255 blue:207.0/255 alpha:1.0]

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = THEME_COLOR_BLUE;
}
```

And I understand, that I could use this as a workaround...

But I'm still curious what is going wrong with my storyboard. Why does it work for iPhone, but not iPad? I'd prefer to use a pure "visual" solution (makes the storyboard easier to edit).

**SOLUTION:**

For some strange reason the fix is to set the background color of the "Content View" (and not for its parent - the "Table View Cell". Here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2rZq.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: were you also able to set the separator color?

Comment: I am not sure, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the background for the cell and then it's contentViews background and you'll discover what's happening.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = YOURCOLOR
```

// For static try setting it in willDisplayCell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = YOURCOLOR
}
```

Comment: Oh ok - when I set the "Content View" background color (and not for the "Table View Cell" as originally in my storyboard) - then it works both for iPad and iPhone.